# RFID communication protocol programming

Tags: arduino, rfid

I have proposed an [RFID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification) protocol, and I would like to implement it.

The tag has to read, write and needs to calculate [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), XOR and concatenation operators.

The tag and reader have to generate random numbers.

This is an example of two steps of the protocol:

For example, the tag has to perform this function and send it to the reader:

- Reader -> Tag : R1
- Tag -> Reader:  M1= PRNG( R1 || R2), where R1 and R2 are random numbers generated by reader and tag respectively.
- Then the reader will send M1 and random numbers to server (SQL): Reader -> Server: R1, R2, M1

When the authentication is successful, both the tag and server have to update their data.

Where do I start from? I saw many tutorials on reading and writing data to RFID tags, but they are very basic.

I saw many tutorials where the microcontroller for example ([Arduino Uno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino#ArduinoUno)) performs all the computations, but I want the tag to perform, not the microcontroler.

How do I get started and are there some tutorials?

Comment: A tag can't "read, write and calculate...", the tag actually are just like a barcode with steroids. You can read a tag with a reader or write in the tag with a reader. that's it.

Comment: Thanks for replying. so how can the tag generate random numbers??? If we suppose that in a challenge response protocol where the reader generates a random number (R_number) and the tag generates a random number (T_number) and responds with a function like F= R_number XOR T_number >> how can this be done

Comment: Again, you can save some info in the tag. You have 4 memory blocks there: `User Bank, TID Bank, EPC Bank, Reserved Bank`. Typically, the memory size per tag is 512bits. So, you can generate your random numbers in the reader and save them in the tag `EPC memory Bank`.  A tag can't generate random numbers as a respond of anything. Btw, I'm talking about `UHF RFID tags`.

Comment: Thanks again. I read in the EPC Class 1 Gen 2 standard that: The tag backscatters a 16-bit random number as it enters the Reply state. So this is my question how this can be done?? I haven't seen any tutorial or code for this.

Comment: Could you paste me the link? I've never seen that feature of the tag.